# Is It Possible to Create CSV File with Multiple Tabs in Command Prompt?

Tags: shell, command-line, csv, batch-file

I'm looking to create a .csv file that can be opened in Excel that displays 2 tabs. However, the catch is that the script that I write has to be in a batch file (command prompt). I've seen a few ways to do this online, but they're all JAVA programs. I'm not sure about doing this in command prompt

Is this even possible?

Comment: .csv indicates one set of data. You could possible research the XML format that is being used by a lot of the MS products to see if you can create multi-tab data sets using that. Won't be a snap of the finger (I don't think). You would definitely want to change some of your tags so MS based developers can help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 28):

Asking excel to save a multiple-sheet workbook as CSV got me this error message:

[image: csv files describe a single sheet]

So, no, not possible.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. He is providing evidence that Excel cannot store multiple tabs within a CSV formatted file, so it is impossible to do what the OP is asking. Maybe the answer isn't worthy of an upvote, but I fail to see how the answer is not at all useful. If the OP intended .XLSX or .XLS instead of .CSV, then the question should be updated and clarified.

Comment: Clearly someone is having a bad day.  There are a lot of questions asked here where I ask myself "Why didn't they just try it?" and simply ignore, but this guy asked a clear question and so I figured I would, given that I didn't know the answer and thought that would be a useful sort of thing to be able to do.

Comment: I was referring to the down vote for your answer - I think your answer is perfectly reasonable, certainly nothing deserving of a down vote. The question - ehh - not much thought went into it, but the question doesn't surprise me.

Comment: And I was referring to the person who downvoted my answer, not you.

Comment: Maybe you got a downvote because the question asked for a technique for a .csv file to be opened as multiple tabs, and you posted a message about saving multiple tabs as .csv, which is not what the question asked.